# How to disable GPU in keras with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I want to compare processing time of my code with and without gpu. My backend of keras is Tensorflow. So it uses a GPU automatically. I use a model of `keras/examples/mnist_mlp.py` for comparing.

I checked the processing time like below. Then, how do I disable my GPU? Should `~/.keras/keras.json` be modified?

```
$ time python mnist_mlp.py 
Test loss: 0.109761892007
Test accuracy: 0.9832
python mnist_mlp.py  38.22s user 3.18s system 162% cpu 25.543 total
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? :

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' time python mnist_mlp.py
```

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is usually used to hide some GPU's to cuda. Here you  hide them all as you don't put any visible device.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 time python mnist_mlp.py
```

seems to be a) either the new way, or b) a way that works on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: what do you mean by the `new way`?

Comment: @oak: I mean compared to Nassim Ben's answer.

Comment: ha ok, so only b works under both windows and linux,right?

Comment: Using anything other than a valid gpu ID will default to the CPU, -1 is a good conventional value that is never a valid gpu ID. The problem with the other answer is probably something to do with the quotes not behaving the same on windows. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` should always work.

Comment: `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']='-1'` if it is to be set before the tensorflow import